# how do i retrieve a resourcestree cellvalue and pass it to another class

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am working on a hotel reservation management system project in vb.net. i am using a resourcestree and a scheduler control. i have successfully linked the resourcestree to the scheduler control and all the resources are displayed in the resourcestree.
Now i will like that when i do a click or a double click on a cell value in the resourcestree, it should open up a UC which is another scheduler,showing just the clicked cell value name and its reservations. please help me out.
below is the event handler am trying to use but it retrieves nothing as value.

i tried using the resources tree row cellclick but nothing .
i need to retrieve the resourcestree cellvalue and all the reservation belongs to that resource. please any ideas

```vb
 Private Sub ResourcesTree1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles ResourcesTree1.RowCellClick
        Try
           
            Dim room_Renamed As Rooms = TryCast(e.CellValue, Rooms)

            If room_Renamed IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim booking_Renamed As Bookings = GetBooking(room_Renamed)
                Me.ShowRoomDetails(room_Renamed, booking_Renamed, "Overview")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

rooms is declared as a public class
bookings is declared as a public class

Comment: When you say _but it retrieves nothing_ what exactly does this mean?  Are you meaning TryCast(e.CellValue, Rooms) is failing so room_Renamed is Nothing or the ShowRoomDetails method not doing what is expected? Notice you've got an empty catch block there, is there exceptions happening you're not handling? In short, probably need more debugging info

Comment: room_renamed is nothing, that's what am trying to say.

Comment: if room_renamed is nothing then it doesn't enter the if statement which is what i don't want. i want room_renamed to be equal to that cell value.